# Check if a quantity is within some measurement in pint in python

Tags: python, pint

I want to check whether a single quantity is within a measurement. Or if a measurement is within a measurement. ie, this should return True:

```
import pint
u=pint.UnitRegistry()
a=(1*u.m).plus_minus(0.1, relative=True)
(1.05*u.m).within(a)
```

Is this functionality/use case at all supported?

Comment: In the [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation they state that uncertainties are handled through the [uncertainties package](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/). You may want to have a look at that one then.

Comment: @Daniel R. I have looked at uncertainties and they don't handle "pint quantities" (I think) - so that would mean that pint would somehow have to make sense of uncertainties' measurement class.

Comment: mhmh they say that `ndarray methods and ufuncs can be used in Quantity objects`. The documentation of `uncertainties` has [this](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/numpy_guide.html#arrays) suggestion for building numpy arrays objects with uncertainties, you might try to copy the array presented as an example and perform some operations such as `+` on a `Quantity` object and see what happens. I'll have a look in the definition of the Quantity object meanwhile and see what can be found there.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/blob/master/pint/quantity.py) is the code for the Quantity object, and while it contains references to `deltas` in the values, it is poorly documented notwithstanding the sparse comments present. The way I would handle it is to perform the computation on the errors first, and then instantiating the quantity object only when/if you need to do a unit conversion.